# How to parse a JSON in a GET HTTP in Ionic Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to perform the following tasks within a Ionic/Cordova application. I need to perform a GET request method to download this:

```
{"fantaAllenatori":[{"Posizione":1,"FantaAllenatore":"Player1","Punti":"6","V":"1","P":"0","S":"0"},{"Posizione":2,"FantaAllenatore":"Player2","Punti":"5","V":"1","P":"0","S":"0"}]}
```

So I mapped the object in this way (rankRows.ts):

```
export interface RankRow {
   posizione: number;
   FantaAllenatore: String;
   Punti: String;
   V: String;
   P: String;
   S: String;
}
```

And this is the fanta fanta calcio.service.ts, the module that handles the connections with the ResAPI server:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EnvService } from './env.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RankRow } from '../models/rankRow';

export class RankRowsResponse {
  data: RankRow[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FantacalcioService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private env: EnvService,
    private authenticationService : AuthenticationService){}


    getMatchDay(){
      return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'matchday.php').toPromise()
      .then(respone =>{
        console.log(respone);
      })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.log(error);
    })
    }

    getRank(){
      var json;
      let headers = { headers: this.authenticationService.getHeadersToken(), withCredentials: true};
      return this.http.get<RankRowsResponse>(this.env.API_URL + 'classifica.json', headers).pipe(
        map(prsp => {prsp.data;
        console.log(prsp.data.length)}));
   }
}
```

Where am I wrong? I'm not to able to get the light of the array so I guess I'm not able to fetch the data.

Comment: What is the error? Where do you call the service methods ?

Comment: no need to parse json `HttpClientModule` do this by default

Comment: @TheUnreal I'm calling it in the onIinit  ngOnInit() method

Comment: ... share the code and what is your error...

Comment: just return this :  `return this.http.get<RankRowsResponse>(this.env.API_URL + 'classifica.json', headers);` and subscribe to the observable where you are calling the service

Comment: No need to parse JSON. Try this: `this.http.get('https://someapi.com/posts').subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib good hints it works!

Comment: `Posizione` is titlecase in your response, while it is lowercase in your interface

Answer (score 0):

You are not `return` from your `map` function:

```
return this.http.get<RankRowsResponse>(this.env.API_URL + 'classifica.json', headers)
    .pipe(
        map(prsp => {
        console.log(prsp.data.length);
        return prsp;
     }));
```

Or just use `subscribe` method:

```
return this.http.get<RankRowsResponse>(this.env.API_URL + 'classifica.json', headers)
    .subscribe( res => 
        return res;
     }));
```

The `pipe` method allows to chain observable operators, and the `subscribe` is to activate the observable and to listen emitted values.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**for model:**

```
export class RankRow {
    posizione: number;
    FantaAllenatore: String;
    Punti: String;
    V: String;
    P: String;
    S: String;
}
```

**In component:**

```
datalist:RankRow ;

this.service.GetDataList().subscribe(result => {this.datalist= result;});
```

Comment: Please no. You are not unsubscribing here, his promise is a better approach.